# Where is Sheru's water tank located in real life?

Tags: film-location, lion

In the film *Lion*, The water tank remembered by Saroo in Khandwa appears in Google Maps to be situated across the road from a bus stand, and just southwest of Khandwa platform 2:

[image]

However, in the movie, when Dev Patel as Saroo recognises the water tower in Google Earth, it is a water tower just east of a completely different railway line:

[image]

I suppose this is just film maker's licence, but I am intrigued, is this other water tower somewhere nearby? Where is it?

Comment: An interesting one, this. In the film you see him zooming in on the real water tower and train station but then when it cuts back the close-up shot is of an entirely different tower.

Answer (score 2):

With some geographical sleuthing I have answered my own question!

The image from the film is of a water tower at Bagat Ki Kothi Railway Station in the south of the city of Jodhpur, about 650 km north west of Khandwa.

The tower's location - 73.1051° East, 26.2537° North.

Here is a more recent image of this location:
[image]

So yes, Film maker's licence I guess!

I still love the movie though and this doesn't detract from it in any real sense.

Just as an addendum to this answer, the actual water tower that Saroo Brierley remembered was not the one in Khandwa, it was one near the station in Burhanpur: 76.198996° East, 21.335329° North:

[image]

Comment: Are you manning to visit? If so, you might want to take some snaps and add them to the filming location website https://www.latlong.net/location/lion-locations-841

Comment: Not actually planning to visit, though I would love to. I have put a comment on that site. Thanks for sending the link.